# VS Code Pylint unresolved import on not yet installed package

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, package, python-import, pylint

The structure of my package is the following:

```
package
|___package
|        |_subpackage
|        |            |_ __init__.py
|        |            |_ module_Y.py
|        |_ __init__.py
|        |_ module_X.py
|_ main.py
|_ setup.py
```

My `__init__.py` files are all empty and `module_Y.py` has the line `from package import module_X`.

I have not yet installed the package since it's not even remotely close to be working, but I want Pylint to be able to understand that the import statement in `module_Y.py` is going to be correct. I know that this **must** be possible because cloning the repo of [TF-Agents](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents) and opening it in VS code, pylint understand the references inside the files<sup>1</sup> even if I have not yet installed the TF-agents repo.

I know that I could use relative imports like `from .. import module_X`, and I know that I could just disable these pylint warnings, but these two me are half solutions. The first is not as clean and clear as the statement `from package import module_X` and the second solution possibly doesn't tell me of something being actually wrong.

What am I missing?

<sup>1<sub>Take for example `tf_agents/agents/dqn/dqn_agent.py` which is able to resolve the imports to `tf_agents.policies`</sub></sup>

Comment: if you want to use pylint and remove all waring, i suggest you to read [pylint documentation](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/) and see how it make check and do accordingly

Comment: @sahasrara62 As I said in the question, I know that I could disable the pylint warning, but that is not what I want to do here. I want Pylint to warn me of possible faulty imports, but I want it to understand that this import statement is actually correct once the package is setup

Comment: that is why i said, see how pylint check the imports and try to make your project import accordingly

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I reproduced this problem, the following is my solution and you could refer to it:

Way 1:

1. Please add the following code at the beginning of the file "`module_Y.py`", which adds the file path to the upper level directory "`package`":

> ```
> import sys
> sys.path.append("..")
> ```

2. Please set `"cwd": "${fileDirname}",` in "[launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations)";
3. Click `F5` to debug the code: (Since this warning does not affect the use of the code, we can close it after the code is available: use `"python.analysis.disabled": [ "unresolved-import" ],` in settings.json )

   [image]

Way 2:

Or you could also set in "`launch.json`":  (It adds the folder path of the current workspace to the system path.)

> ```
> "env": {
>                 "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
>             },
> ```

[image]

Comment: Ok, method 1) is not substantially different fhan just `from .. import module_x` and in your screen it doesn't seem to solve the Pylint warning.
Method 2) is more kind of what I was looking for, but it's not automatic, i.e. if I just clone the repo on a new PC I will also have to go change the launch.json file in it (unless I push it to git, which is undesirable). 
Did you have a look at the tf-agents repo I mentioned? Because they actually use neither of these methods, and still manage to have pylint not put warnings all around the place...

Comment: ... And  the crucial thing is that it's not just the warning that are missing in the TF-Agents repo, but rather I can 'Go to Deinition` even though the package is not yet installed and VS Code manages to figure out somehow where the definition is (even though there is no launch.json file)

Comment: @Federico Malerba -When importing files from other folders, VSCode starts from the parent folder of the current file by default. Therefore, we need to add the project path to the system path by setting the file, or add the file path to the same level folder path in.
In addition, according to this search rule, you could try to put "module_X.py" into the "subpackage", and it does not need to use the settings.json and launch.json file.